# get number of updates since a timestamps in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we get the number of updates since a particular timestamps using graph APIS? Number of updates might be number of new New feed or Messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on which api you are calling

> When searching for public posts or posts on the user's News Feed, you
>   can page over the results by using the since, until and limit
>   parameters. since and until both accept a unix timestamp. When paging
>   back in time, you should use until in conjunction with limit where
>   until is the unixtime value of the created_time field in the last
>   object returned by your previous query. When paging forward in time
>   you should set since to be the unixtime value of the created_time
>   field in the first object returned by your previous query. Please
>   note, you can only search about 1 to 2 weeks back in the News Feed.

/me/feed?since=2+hours+ago&until=now  "using strtotime in php"